# Calling REST APIs without storing SF credentials on the client side

Tags: rest-api, jsforce, salesforce-sdk-hybrid

I have 5 orgs that I want to be linked to my web server. My server gets POST calls from different Facebook accounts. These then have to be routed to Salesforce orgs according to the business that calls it.

I want to know how I can achieve this without having to store credentials of the user of each org.

Right now, I am hardcoding these credentials in a map in my server's main app.js file, but I want a permanent approach.

I am using heroku and have not connected a db, but am open to it. For making connections, I am using jsforce. Also exploring @salesforce/salesforce-sdk.

Comment: oAuth would be the first place I would suggest you read up on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably going to be using one of two Connected App solution approaches:

1. an [OAuth Refresh Token](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5) (stored securely by your server) for each of your 5 orgs. You will likely use the web server flow to prompt a user in the org to grant your app access to their org as them. (This might be an integration user / named principal) You'll then use that stored oauth refresh token to request a session token to access the org as this user.
2. use a [JWT Bearer token flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) to request a session token for a given username in each org. The key difference with this flow is that the connected app must be pre-authorized in the org in order to allow your app to login as the given user (known within the JWT as the subject `sub` or principal `prn`).

Comment: This is a server to SF integration. Will check out using JWT as it looks relevant for my use case. Thanks!